# Add Savepoint to Datastream

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a kafka source from which my flink application reads data and process it, i want to add flink's savepoint mechanism in order to resume the process  from last where it was left, Instead of adding savepoint to the kafka source i want my application to maintain the state of the last processed stream, so that it do not reprocesses my data which is being partially processed by my application.

I've added save point to kafka source which resume the kafka stream but the instead i want to resume my processed data stream

```
 DataStream<String> streamOfStrings = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(topicname));
```

My string stream is further passed to another process which is converted into Datastream of an Object. I want the state of the processed stream should only to be maintained but not the kafka stream. Is there any way to attach save point to a datastream

```
 DataStream<Object> streamOfObject = App.convertToObject(streamOfStrings);
```

Comment: Do you accept at-least-once semantics for the convertToObject?

Answer (score 0):

A few clarifications...

1. Even if you're maintaining downstream state, the Kafka source has to maintain some state to know how much of the topic it has consumed; when you restart from a checkpoint or savepoint, it has to replay any data from the time of the last data that made it into the saved state, and the current data that's available.
2. Any state that you're saving needs to have some duration (typically a time limit) on it, so that it doesn't accumulate unbounded, right?

The simplest approach I can think of is to turn your `App.convertToObject()` method into a proper function that implements the `[ListCheckpointed][1]` interface. You'd save each converted object to a list, up to some limit (see the BufferingSink example on the same page).